# OAuth Redirect URI with Port Forwarding on Unusual Port

Tags: oauth-2.0, redirect, portforwarding

I have HTTPS server running on port `4443` and am using port forwarding to send `443` -> `4443` so in the browser you can't tell

In my OAuth settings when I use `https://www.domain.com:4443/callback` I get the response but in the popup it can't access the parent and I get this Chrome error

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.domain.com:4443" from accessing a 
frame with origin "https://www.domain.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

When I change the url in the OAuth to 443 I get the beloved

```
`Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key.`
```

The only way I can think of is checking via javascript if the port is is the url, and if so to redirect to the url without the port.

Are there any more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has come up with an elegant solution, I thought I'd put my Javascript redirect answer.

What I did was, inside the window that accepts the redirect whose URL will look something like `https://www.domain.com:4443/callback?aribtrary_data=1231252...etc...` I wrap my callback code inside a try statement. If it fails, I redirect the current page to the same URL minus the port numbers.

Here's my Jade popup window solution which attempts to call the parent window upon finishing.

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Authentication Popup
        script.
            var service = !{JSON.stringify(service)},
                callback = 'on' + service.name + 'Auth';

            window.onload = function () {
                try {
                    window.opener[callback](service.error, service);
                    window.close();
                } catch (e) {
                    window.location = window.location.href.replace(/(\.com)(:\d{3,4})?/, '$1');
                }
            }
    body
        | Closing in 1...
```